# Screen unlock pattern fails

Tags: lock-screens, pattern-lock

After a system crash, it black screen and reboots, i am unable to unlock using a pattern, it is correct but is not recognised. I don't want to exceed the retry limit as things get more complicated...

How to fix it?

I'm stuck with android 6.0.1 on a galaxy j7 2015.

Answer (score 1):

This happened 2 times already. I just had to calm down and think: the reboot was forced, in a non safe way. So something went wrong.

To solve it, i just did another, but normal reboot, and it fixed itself.